# Different behavior of HTML <input> checked Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, input

Different behavior is occurring in different browser for HTML `<input>` attribute. I have generated `input` attribute from Javascript by clicking a button. Checkbox is visible in Firefox browser but not showing in Chrome browser. The generated HTML code is

```
<input id="0" class="col-sm-1" onclick="checkImage(this)" name="images[0].isActiveDefault" type="checkbox">
```

**FireFox Browser**

[image]

**Chrome Browser**

[image]

Any help or suggestion to resolve this problem will be appreciate.

**EDIT** added JavaScript Code

```
function addImagerow(tableId) {
    var rowValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('image-add').value);
    var tableData = "<tr><td><input id = '"
        + rowValue
        + "' class='col-sm-1' onclick='checkImage(this)' name='images["
        + rowValue
        + "].isActiveDefault' type='checkbox'></td><td>Default</td>"
        + "<tr>";
    document.getElementById('image-add').value = rowValue + 1;
    $(tableData).appendTo(tableId);
}
```

Comment: Please post the JS code where you create the checkbox. If you copy and paste that tag directly into your HTML code, does it show up?

Comment: @MátéSafranka yes it works if I copy paste directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having waste a lot of time I found the issue. Though the issue is silly, I have learned a lesson from it. Ok, the issue was on the design.  From the `input field` I remove the `class='col-sm-1'`. And its working fine.

> I added the `bootstrap css` for `input field` but not for  `table data field`.

```
var tableData = "<tr><td><input id = '"
    + rowValue
    + "' class='col-sm-1' onclick='checkImage(this)' name='images["
    + rowValue
    + "].isActiveDefault' type='checkbox'></td><td>Default</td>"
    + "<tr>";
```

**TO**

```
var tableData = "<tr><td><input id = '"
    + rowValue
    + "onclick='checkImage(this)' name='images["
    + rowValue
    + "].isActiveDefault' type='checkbox'></td><td>Default</td>"
    + "<tr>";
```

And my analysis says that I when I added the `col-sm-1` into the input field the `<td>` is not expanding that's why the `input field` is hide.